# Script for getting OS of a machine in AD then If statement

Tags: powershell, ps

I have a script here that gets the OS of machines in AD. It is working fine and displaying the OS in the csv file. What I'd like to do now is to insert an if statement that if the OS is Windows 10 or Windows 7, it will input Workstation in the csv. And if it is Mac then it will say Workstation Mac in the csv. Not so sure where to insert the If statement here. Any help will do. Thanks

```
$comps = ForEach ($comp in $(Get-Content "C:\computers.txt")) {

    Get-AdComputer $comp -Properties OperatingSystem

}

$comps |
Select-Object OperatingSystem |
Export-CSV -Path "C:\Asset.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `Select-Object` and a calculated property:

```
$typeSelector = @{
  Name = 'Type'
  Expression = {
    switch -wildcard ($_.OperatingSystem)
    {
      '*Windows*' { return 'Workstation'}
      '*Mac*' { return 'Workstation Mac'}
      default { return 'Unknown' }
    }
  }
}

$comps |Select-Object OperatingSystem,$typeSelector |Export-CSV -Path "C:\Asset.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

`Select-Object` will evaluate the the expression against each item in `$comps` and attach a new property named `Type` with the result

Comment: wow that works Mathias! Im just a newbie in PS. First time seeing switch and that code. do you have a link where I can read re that @{ Name = 'Type' Expression = { switch }